swapping escape and caps lock using via
What i did
I have a keychron k2 pro (keyboard) which uses via as its firmware. Now i want to swap esc and caps lock keys, so i do, i use the via webapp on my windows installation and swap the keys in two of the three layers that were configured and had caps lock and escape keys defined (i have no clue what those layers are for btw). After that it worked on my windows, booting up linux however i noticed that the keys weren't changed by trial and also using wev to show the events wayland receives directly.
Confusion
Now i thought that i had changed the firmware on my keyboard, so why hasn't the behaviour changed on linux.
would appreciate any help

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Not the most in-depth article, but might help: https://www.keychron.com/blogs/archived/how-to-use-via-to-program-your-keyboard
